# How to make a single page scroller work in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

In my Joomla 2.5, I have a single page scroller that points to anchors on a page like:

```
<li><a href="#um"><i class="uk-icon-circle"></i></a></li>  
<li><a href="#dois"><i class="uk-icon-circle"></i></a></li>  
<li><a href="#tres"><i class="uk-icon-circle"></i></a></li>
```

Each of the three anchors is located at the top, middle and bottom of the page, respectively.

Although the links are correct, they don't scroll the page to the area they're supposed to. In fact, nothing happens, when I click.

I tried typing the urls directly:[anchor1](http://cfo.portal-gestao.com/#um) [anchor 2](http://cfo.portal-gestao.com/#dois)
[anchor 3](http://cfo.portal-gestao.com/#tres) and they seem to be correct.

Is there any alternative to build this kind of scroller, or is the code above wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I answered this question here that might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20347465/1811992

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.